# Simple Pandas Groupby/Pivot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame

```
    Value     Date
0       1  2022-01-01
1       2  2022-01-01
2       3  2022-01-01
3       4  2022-01-02
4       5  2022-01-02
5       6  2022-01-02
6       7  2022-01-03
7       8  2022-01-03
8       9  2022-01-03
```

I would like to obtain the following DataFrame, by grouping all the values associated with a  given date:

```
Date    2022-01-01    2022-01-02    2022-01-03
0                1             4             7
1                2             5             8
2                3             6             9
```

I know this should be a really simply task, but I'm struggling to figure it out. I have used
`df.groupby('Date')['Value].apply(list).to_frame.T`, but that didn't work. Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option can be to use [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and then drop `nan` values.

```
df_new = df.pivot(columns='Date', values='Value').apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)).astype('int')

print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
Date  2022-01-01  2022-01-02  2022-01-03
0              1           4           7
1              2           5           8
2              3           6           9
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on [`pivot_wider`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) of package `pyjanitor`:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

(df.set_index(df.index % 3)
 .pivot_wider(names_from = 'Date', values_from = 'Value')
 .rename_axis('Date', axis=1))
```

Output:

```
Date  2022-01-01  2022-01-02  2022-01-03
0              1           4           7
1              2           5           8
2              3           6           9
```